# Selenium is very slow , any alternative?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

URL - https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch

Using **selenium** I can extract data from the above URL but the process is very slow. Is there any way I can extract data using **request library** only?

I wanted the text shown in the image [image] to extract.

My code to extract data using selenium -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=option)


driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch')
time.sleep(5) 
      
html_text2 = driver.page_source
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_text2,'lxml')


data1 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text.strip()
data2 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)").text.strip()
    
wb = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
ws  = wb.active
fontstyle = Font(size = "16")
ws['B9'].value = f'{data1}  {data2}'
ws.cell(row = 9 , column = 2).font = fontstyle

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: @KlausD. : He has already shown his efforts, see these two lines `data1 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text.strip()
data2 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)").text.strip()` they are bs4

Comment: First I tried to use beautifulsoup with request library only but I was getting an error (nonetype) . Then I used selenium. But I think It can be extracted by beautiulsoup also but I don't know how

Comment: @cruisepandey No, he has shown his Selenium based code only. The phrase "using beautifulsoup only" is misleading since it can not get any data from the server. That was Selenium's part. I guess he wants to use requests or similar. But we will know once he supplies details about his attempts.

Comment: Please update the question with your attempt and the full error message!

Comment: @KlausD. :  I am not sure what you are talking about, but this is BS `html_text2 = driver.page_source
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_text2,'lxml')


data1 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text.strip()
data2 = soup2.find("span" , "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)").text.strip()`

Comment: there's no method called `find` in Selenium, it is available in BS4

Comment: @cruisepandey The code is completely unrelated to the problem, which is to replace Selenium not beautifulsoup. And BTW "this is BS" is a very unfortunate choice of words.

Comment: @AnimeshSingh : You initially mentioned you are looking for solution in BS4, now you have changed the entire heading/post description. Please be clearer about your post. folks here invest time and efforts to solve problem. Anyone can click on the edited link and can see what was originally posted.

Comment: Let me explain what I meant. We generally use a combination of two libraries to scrap data. One to extract full JSON of a webpage(request,urllib etc) and the other to scrape out the required data(generally beutifulsoup). Here while using selenium, extraction of json is becoming quite slow. I wanted a way to fast this process because it is a dynamic website and we cant't use request library to extract JSON.

Comment: Now I found a library called request-html. It works with dynamic websites as well .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css_selector :

```
div>span[data-reactid='31']
```

which has unique entry in **HTMLDOM**.

in Beautiful soup, we use `select` for css not `find`.

```
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch')
time.sleep(5)

html_text2 = driver.page_source
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_text2, 'lxml')

info = [i.text.strip() for i in soup2.select("div>span[data-reactid='31']")]
print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace chrome() with PhantomJS() in the webdriver line after installing latest phantomjs.
PhantomJS is a discontinued headless browser used for automating web page interaction.
You can try using urllib and post directly to the login link. You can use cookiejar to save cookies. You can even simply save cookie, after all, a cookie is simply a string in http header.

It is not always the selenium which is slow. sometimes we need to look at code we are using.

Comment: I used request_html for data scraping.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to get that data pretty fast.

That data is present inside a `<div>` with attributes `data-reactid` = `30`. You can select that `<div>` and extract the data from it.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch&guccounter=1'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

d = soup.find('div', {'data-reactid': '30'})
print(list(d.stripped_strings))
```

```
['26.70', '-0.00 (-0.01%)', 'At close:  5:35PM CEST']
```